# Total model loss is greater than sum of the the model's outputs loss

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a multi input multi output which take an image and a numpy array as an input with output of 2 regression values , while training i notice that the total loss of the model is greater than the sum of the two outputs , what does it mean ?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to completely understand your problem, but from what I can comprehend is that unless your val loss and total loss is approximately near by then your  model is going good, basically both of your losses should not differ much. For this kind of problems try and use tensorBoard to get graphical output for your model performance and check if model loss and val loss are varying closely or is there any hindrance.